# Multiple integral 3 dimension

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, volume

> Find the volume of the body
>   $$ v:{(x,y,z) :\quad   x^2+y^2\le z \le \sqrt{2-x^2-y^2}}.$$

I really don't know what to beside that i have to do triple integral of one.

My main problem is to understand the domains (do i need to use Jacobian?).

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it is $+y^2$ under the square root?

Comment: Yes and it corrected it to  $$ -y^2 $$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hint

The graph shows in a 2D way the graph of $z$ (vertical axis) against $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. The blue shaded area is $z\ge r^2$, the other area is the other inequality. So you are interested in the overlap. You have to rotate it about the vertical axis (through the centre) to get the solid, whose volume you have to find.